# Can't upload file and convert it to base64string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to upload file, then convert it to base64 string and add to object. but it seems did'nt work.
console.log() every time show empty object

```
<input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" />
<input type="submit" value="send" (click)="upload()" />
```

functions:

```
onChange(fileInput: any) {
    let image: any = fileInput.target.files[0];
    let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = () => {
        reader.readAsDataURL(image);

        let photo: AddPhoto = new AddPhoto();
        photo.base64Image = reader.result;
        this.product.photos = [];
        this.product.photos.push(photo);
    };
}

upload() {
    console.log(this.product);
}
```

Comment: Try replacing the first line insilde "onChange" function as:  let image: any = fileInput.target[0].files;   It worked for me this way some time back. You will then have to iterate over the image variable to get the multiple files which it could have.

Comment: This is how i did it using jQuery: var files = $("#inputFile")[0].files;
           
           
           var data = new FormData();
      $.each(files, function(key, value)
      {
          data.append("file", value);
      });

Comment: Think with jquery it will be simple for me, but now i am trying to get it with angular2.

Comment: One thing here is that, reader.onload will be called only when the file is successfully loaded by reader.readAsDataURL(). Here logically it should not be written inside reader.onload. Take readAsDataURL outside the onload function so that it remains inside onChange function. Then it should work.

Comment: @Luke P. Issac thanks, it started to work. I am new at stackowerflow. How can i mark your answer?

Comment: Now, i have posted it as answer. You should be able to mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing here is that, reader.onload will be called only when the file is successfully loaded by reader.readAsDataURL(). Here logically it should not be written inside reader.onload. Take readAsDataURL outside the onload function so that it remains inside onChange function. Then it should work. You code should look something as follows.

```
    onChange(fileInput: any) {
        let image: any = fileInput.target.files[0];
        let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();


        reader.onload = () => {
            let photo: AddPhoto = new AddPhoto();
            photo.base64Image = reader.result;
            this.product.photos = [];
            this.product.photos.push(photo);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(image);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me...hope it helps

```
uploadFileImage(fileInput: any)
{
    var files = fileInput.target.files;
    var file = files[0];

    if (files && file) 
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(readerEvt: any) 
        {
            var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
            var base64 = btoa(binaryString);
            this.product.photos = [];
            this.product.photos.push(base64);
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: **TypeError: this.product is undefined.** Can't access class field from sub function